# Help with trigger defaulting multi-select picklist fields

Tags: trigger, update, upsert

I'm fairly new to coding and my admin has asked me to create a couple of triggers to update a multi-select picklist for our Opportunity page or maybe I could combine them into one. I have created the pseudo code for the triggers I need to code, but I'm struggling with the syntax. The following is my pseudo code:

```
trigger UpdateOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {    
    for (Opportunity)    
        if (win_reason = no competitor)     
            then    
            Competitor(s) = No Competiton/Sole Source

        if (Unsolicited Bid = "Yes")    
            then    
            Competitor(s) = No Competiton/Sole Source    
}
```

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What part of the syntax are you struggling with? Your pseudo code looks pretty good in terms of structure.

Comment: What's the MultiSelect Field?  Competitor__c?  MutliSelect Fields have a special syntax where as Picklist & Text fields follow the same rules

Comment: Thanks Alex. I guess I'm looking for advice on the logic. Can you use If/then statements? Is that the correct way to go about, if a=b then c=d? I do realize that I need to use the actually API name for the fields but any other advice?

Comment: That is correct, amatorVitae.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some the gaps filled in.  I am assuming that `Competitor__c` is your MultiSelect field, that `Win_Reason__c` is a Picklist and that `Unsolicited_Bid__c` is a Checkbox.  If not, adjust accordingly.

```
------------------------------------------------------
-- Field Type    *  Data Type                       --
------------------------------------------------------
-- Picklist      *  String                          --
-- Text          *  String                          --
-- Checkbox      *  Boolean                         --
-- MultiSelect   *  String with ; to delimit values --
-- Number        *  Decimal                         --
-- Currency      *  Decimal                         --
-- Date          *  Date                            --
-- Datetime      *  Datetime                        --
-- Master-Detail *  Id                              --
-- Loookup       *  Id                              --
-- TextArea      *  String                          --
------------------------------------------------------

trigger UpdateOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update){    
    for(Opportunity opp :Trigger.new){ 

        // MultiSelect Fields are a single String with values delimited by a semi-colon

        // TODO: Double check Field API Names
        // TODO: Double check Field values spelling for Case Sensitivity 
        if(opp.win_reason__c == 'No Competitor'){   
            opp.Competitor__c = 'No Competiton;Sole Source'; 
        }
        if(opp.Unsolicited_Bid__c == true){  
            opp.Competitor__c = 'No Competiton;Sole Source';
        } 
    }   
}
```

---

Here's some helpful docs when working with Triggers:

- [Trigger Context Variables](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)
- [Trigger Context Variables Considerations](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm)

---

### Update

To neatly add the condition **not** to have the above execute if the `Stage = 0%`, I will introduce using an Apex Class static function.  Separating what we are doing into individual *methods* simplifies logic and code-readability.

First let's create an Apex Class:

```
public Class OpportunityMethods {

    public static void updateOppCompetitor(Opportunity opp){
        if(opp.win_reason__c == 'No Competitor'){   
            opp.Competitor__c = 'No Competiton;Sole Source'; 
        }
        if(opp.Unsolicited_Bid__c == true){  
            opp.Competitor__c = 'No Competiton;Sole Source';
        } 
    }

}
```

Now rewrite the trigger to use the `OpportunityMethods.updateOppCompetitor(...)` method:

```
trigger UpdateOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update){    
    for(Opportunity opp: trigger.new){
        OpportunityMethods.updateCompetitor(opp);
    }  
}
```

Cool.  The rewritten trigger does look a bit simpler.  But we still need to only `updateOppCompetitor` if the `opp.StageName != 0 %`.  (Or you might be referring to the `opp.Probability = 0` where the Opportunity Probability is a decimal, so adjust accordingly.)  To do this, let's add a simple if statement and execute `updateCompetitor(opp)` if `opp.StageName != '0 %'`:

```
trigger UpdateOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update){    
    for(Opportunity opp: trigger.new){
        if(opp.StageName != '0 %'){
            OpportunityMethods.updateOppCompetitor(opp);  
        }
    }  
}
```

Double cool.  That does exactly what we want it to do, *and* just reading the code tell us simply what it's doing.

Being astute, we notice, "Hey, could put that StageName-condition in the `updateCompetitor` method directly?"  And the answer is, "Yes.  Furthermore, instead of sending each `Opportunity` through the method, we could send the whole `List<Opportunity>` through and do all the processing there in a method."

One path to realizing this is through the following:   First let's add to our `OpportunityMethods` class

```
public Class OpportunityMethods {

    public static void updateOppCompetitor(Opportunity opp){
        if(opp.win_reason__c == 'No Competitor'){   
            opp.Competitor__c = 'No Competiton;Sole Source'; 
        }
        if(opp.Unsolicited_Bid__c == true){  
            opp.Competitor__c = 'No Competiton;Sole Source';
        } 
    }

    public static void updateComptetitor(List<Opportunity> newList){
        for(Opportunity op :newList){
            if(opp.StageName != '0 %'){
                OpportunityMethods.updateOppCompetitor(opp);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the trigger simplifies to:

```
trigger UpdateOpportunity on Opportunity (before insert, before update){    
    OpportunityMethods.updateCompetitor(trigger.new);  
}
```

Notice how we re-used the `updateOppCompetitor`-method in the `updateCompetitor`-method.  We already did the work of writing the method, so let's reuse what we have.  Also, with any type of code, there are many ways to go about accomplishing the same end result.  The key to good programming is having the flexibility to accomplish the same results using various paths -- sometimes certain paths offer a much shorter route than others, and each path-lengths depends on the destination.  When Limits are imposed on a situations, *cough cough Governor Limits*, some paths may be closed off, so it's handy to know alternative routes when necessary.

Comment: Hi amatorVitae, I'm back for help. I would like to now perform this trigger on every stage besides when a Lead is = 0%. How would I exclude this trigger from functioning when Stage= Lead 0%? Thanks again.

Comment: Check out the update

Comment: amatorVitae, thank you so much for your help and the extensiveness in your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. Can I please take you out for a beer sometimes or something? Or maybe I'll just listen to your music. Any way to pay you back, my friend.